# Renaming the tag human-biology to humans

Tags: discussion, tags

The tag [human-biology](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/human-biology) seems a bit redundant to me, as everthing on this site is about biology.

I propose to rename it to just [humans](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/humans), to bring it in line with all the other tags on the site. Please post your counter-arguments here if you disagree.

Answer (score 2):

I like your proposal, and I would go one step further. Currently there are 5 tags for humans:

- human-genetics
- human-genome
- human-anatomy
- human-ear
- human-biology

I propose that we merge genetics/genome to "human-genetics"; anatomy, ear and biology to "human-physiology" to make the tag more descriptive.

Comment: I think this is a better proposal than just a blanket "humans"

Comment: Thanks John. You can upvote my answer too. =)

Comment: I think human biology itself is an unnecessary tag.. most of our research is already anthropocentric..

for example genetics is genetics.. what is special about human genetics.. it sounds like a journal name..